# ASP Edit GridView Style

Tags: css, asp.net, gridview, styles

Using the examples posted [here](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Edit-Update-and-Delete-in-ASPNet-GridView-with-AutoGenerateColumns-True-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx), I have everything working. The problem is the style. When the gridview loads, it looks amazing. I press Edit, the font, column height, width, etc, all change. How can I edit the style when the EDIT button is pressed to look exactly like the previous style when loaded?

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="CustomerId" OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound" OnRowEditing="OnRowEditing" OnRowCancelingEdit="OnRowCancelingEdit" OnRowUpdating="OnRowUpdating" OnRowDeleting="OnRowDeleting" EmptyDataText="No records has been added." AutoGenerateEditButton="true" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="true">
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the gridview itself:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="Green" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Use the gridview with a stylesheet:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    <EditRowStyle CssClass="myClass" />
</asp:GridView>
```

or use a stylesheet:

```
#GridView1 input { width: 100%; }
```

Comment: You'll probably have to experiment a bit to get it to look exactly the same.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. This worked for me... with a little playing around.